# How do you access the member functions of a class within another class?

Tags: c++

Lets say I have a file such as:

```
//stuff.h
class outer
{
    public:
    print_inner();

    private:
    class inner
    {
        public:
        inner(int stuff){
        //code
        }
    };
};
```

If I want to access the function inner(int stuff) in my main do I do use these following lines for example?

```
//stuff.cpp
include "stuff.h"

outer::print_inner(){
    int a = 4;
    inner* temp = new inner;
    temp.inner(a); // is this how we access our inner function?
    //some more code
}
```

Comment: The stuff.cpp file is the implementation of the h file. My main was not included.

Comment: For a question like this you could try compiling the code into your project to see what breaks.

Comment: There is a lot wrong here. `inner(int stuff)` is a constructor, not a regular function. Your `outer` class has no `inner` member variable; is `inner` intended to be used only statically? Why is it private if you're intending on using it from `main()`? Why is `temp` a pointer? I would take a few steps back and figure out what exactly it is you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `class inner` as nested class in `class outer`.

So to be able to use this class and its members in `outer`,  you first need an object of class `inner`.  Your code is almost correct.

Do either:

```
outer::print_inner(){
    int a = 4;
    inner* temp = new inner;  // pointer to a dynamicly created object
    temp->inner(a); // POINTER INDIRECTION 
    ...   // but don't forget to delete temp when you don't need it anymore
}
```

or

```
outer::print_inner(){
    int a = 4;
    inner temp;  // create a local object 
    temp.inner(a);   // call its member function as usual. 
}
```

By the way,  if `print_innner()` isn't supposed to return a value, you should declare it as `void`.

Comment: Notice that `inner` is the name of the class and not a function!

Comment: Thanks, it seems I was almost correct, except for the part where I forgot that I have to use arrows since I use "new"

Comment: @BeginnerC Try not to use new.

Answer (score 2):

In you specific example, `inner` is a constructor, not a function, and you would want to use `->` syntax if you are using a pointer. Further, `print_inner` needs a return type. E.g.,

```
class outer
{
    public:
    void print_inner();

    private:
    class inner
    {
        public:
        void func(int stuff){
        //code
        }
    };
};

outer::print_inner(){
    int a = 4;
    inner* temp = new inner;
    temp->func(a);
    //some more code
}
```